Existence of Finite Amicable Groups
I'm interested in exploring the concept of "amicable groups" as follows:
Definition. Two finite groups $G$ and $H$ are called amicable groups if:

$G$ is the direct sum of proper subgroups of $H$, and
$H$ is the direct sum of proper subgroups of $G$.

Question. Does there exist a pair of finite amicable groups?
This seems like a natural extension of the concept of amicable numbers, but I'm not aware of any existing research on this topic. Any insights or pointers to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.

I assume one would like $G$ and $H$ to be distinct. So you can take $G=K \times K \times K$ and $H=K \times K \times K \times K$ for any group $K$. Then the proper subgroups are $K$ and $K \times K$ , I guess the next step is to rule out obvious examples like this.

If I understand your question I think by a combinatorial argument the only groups should be $G = H = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ for distinct primes $p$ and $q$.

Do you mean “direct sum of all proper subgroups” ?

Suppose that $G$ and $H$ are nontrivial finite amicable groups and let $\mathscr{G}$ and $\mathscr{H}$ be the  nontrivial proper subgroups of $G$ and $H$, respectively. Then $1 \subsetneq \bigoplus_{S \in \mathscr{H}'} \subsetneq G$ for any nonempty proper subset $\mathscr{H}' \subsetneq \mathscr{H}$, which implies that $|\mathscr{G}| \geq 2^{|\mathscr{H}|} - 2$. Similarly, $|\mathscr{H}| \geq 2^{|\mathscr{G}|} - 2$. It follows that $|\mathscr{G}| = |\mathscr{H}| = 2$.
Hence, $G = H = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ for distinct primes $p$ and $q$.
